# Java Generic Exception

Tags: java, generics, exception

I am dealing with JaudioTagger API to manipulate MP3 files, I have to repeat the following exceptions over and over again... I was thinking of having a generic exception handler where I could forward each exception maybe with a flag number and the generic method would be deal with it by having different switch cases maybe ? Is it possible ? I would really appreciate if someone could give the method signature or a way to call it

```
} catch (CannotReadException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ReadOnlyFileException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InvalidAudioFrameException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (TagException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "repeat exceptions"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pre-JDK 7 all you can do is write a utility function and call it from each of the catch blocks:

```
private void handle(Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

private void someOtherMethod() {
    try {
        // something that might throw
    } catch (CannotReadException ex) {
        handle(ex);
    } catch (ReadOnlyFileException ex) {
        handle(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        handle(ex);
    } catch (InvalidAudioFrameException ex) {
        handle(ex);
    } catch (TagException ex) {
        handle(ex);
    }
}
```

Starting in JDK 7, you can use multi-catch:

```
private void someOtherMethod() {
    try {
        // something that might throw
    } catch (CannotReadException | ReadOnlyFileException | IOException
             | InvalidAudioFrameException | TagException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

See "[Catching multiple exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/adoptionGuide/index.html)".

Answer (score 0):

> **This answer is obsolete starting with Java 7. Use multi-catch like John Watts shows in his answer.**

I suggest using

```
try {
    /* ... your code here ... */
} catch (Exception ex) {
    handle(ex);
}
```

And handle it this way: (you have to replace the OtherException that you don't handle or remove the `throws`)

```
private static void handle(Exception ex) throws SomeOtherException {
    if (ex instanceof CannotReadException || ex instanceof ReadOnlyFileException) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } else if (ex instanceof SomeOtherException) {
        throw (SomeOtherException) ex;
    } else if (ex instanceof RuntimeException) {
        throw (RuntimeException) ex;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```